# How to use the verb "ride"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

To describe cars and busses going up and down Fifth Avenue,can I say:" Cars and busses were RIDING up and down Fifth Avenue"?

Comment: It might be useful if you were writing dialogue and you wanted one character to have a weird manner of speaking. Or it might be off putting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a most unusual way of expressing things.

It's people/passengers/travellers/individuals who ride up and down in buses rather than the buses themselves that ride.

Cars and buses conventionally travel/drive/hurry/move/pass (and many more) up and down.

However, it would not be unusual, after test driving a vehicle with heavy suspension or steering, to say that **the ride was heavy/uncomfortable** or similar, referring to the way that the vehicle handled.

So, you could talk about vehicles riding, and people would understand you, but it would not be idiomatic.